# Map required field to nullable in database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an Entity Framework code-first model in which a Supplier must always have a SupplierGroup:

```
    public virtual SupplierGroup SupplierGroup { get; set; }
    public int SupplierGroupId { get; set; }
```

But the underlying database has to have SupplierGroupId as nullable (due to another system using it, in which a Supplier can exist without a SupplierGroup).

Is there any way to make Entity Framework generate/map to a nullable database-field, but otherwise continue to treat the field in the model as required?

I tried a fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
     .Property(s => s.SupplierGroupId)
     .IsOptional();
```

But when code-first generated the database, the field was still not nullable.

(If a Supplier without a SupplierGroup was ever requested, this should throw an exception as it should never happen).

Comment: Just off the top of my head, have you tried `public int? SupplierGroupId { get; set; }` ?

Comment: @Sameer That is what I'm trying to avoid doing.  I want the model to think it has a non-nullable field, but the database to actually have a nullable one.

Comment: So you want your model to treat a nullable database column as not nullable? I haven't used EF in a while, but what you have in your question should be sufficient. You could try adding the `[Required]` attribute to the `SupplierGroupId` property.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, you want to create a code-first model that generates a database; specifically a table with a nullable column, but which the code-first model should treat as non-nullable. You want to introduce an inconsistency between model and database. So, create the model with the column as nullable, generate the database, and then update the model to treat the column as non-nullable - and be sure that the change isn't migrated to the database.

Comment: @Sameer Thanks for your comments.  My question is really whether the model can be defined as in my example (where SupplierGroup is implicitly required), but when code-first generates the database, a nullable field is created.  So I'm trying to find out if there is some way of setting up this type of mapping & *not* having to do any manual changes.  (BTW adding [Required] would be redundant as "int" can't be null anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to create the database with Entity Framework with the default database initializers in a way that an `int` property would result in a nullable column. As far as I can see your options are:

1. Write a custom database initializer that executes a SQL script which changes the column from not-nullable to a nullable column
2. Don't create the database with Entity Framework, but manually instead (by setting the database initializer to `null` for example), having a nullable column and a not-nullable property
3. Treat your requirement as *application specific* business logic that is not reflected in the database (and can't be because other applications accessing the DB have the requirement to allow `NULL`s), i.e. make the property `int?` and ensure in your application that `null` is never used

For option 1 and 2 your model is "out of sync" with the database which would mean that you'll get exceptions when you load a `Supplier` from the database whose `SupplierGroupId` is `NULL` (probably something like *"...cannot store materialized value NULL in non-nullable property..."*).

I would choose option 3.

Comment: You beat me to it. :) I would also suggest option #3.

Comment: Thanks Slauma.  I went with option 3 - in the end it seemed wrong to try to fool the model that the underlying database was different (not to mention possibly confusing the next developer who works on the code).  Appreciate the answer.